# Login Page Creation AppInventor..?

Tags: android, authentication, app-inventor

How can I create an app in app inventor that login in to my college's web site and fetch student's information such as attendance and academic information. 
The site uses https and also has a CAPTCHA.
I want to know how the username and password are submitted to the server and how the authentication is done..?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do. 
AppInventor does have a WebViewer component which you can use to display webpages, fill in forms and view the results. If you use this in your app then you can interact with the website in much the same way as you would with a browser.
If you want to directly interface with your college's server then you can't use AppInventor unless there is a REST/SOAP service which I suspect there isn't.